# Relative position Element exceed over value in CSS

Tags: html, css, css-position

I set the position to relative and set `top` to `-150px`, but the actual size is different.
What is the problem?
Setting `top` to `0` is OK though.

[image]

Comment: Please go read [ask] and [mre], and then edit your question accordingly. Code relevant to your problem belongs directly into your question, in text form and properly formatted or as a snippet. Do not just post _images of_ code.

Comment: Can you please show in `Codepan or jsfiddle`

Comment: Hi @chakmeshma, can you please provide a minimal HTML/CSS code so we can reproduce this locally. It will help me to understand the issue more clearly. Thanks.

Comment: where. is. the. code?

Comment: can be set up `margin: -150px auto 0`,You did not provide code snippets, so we do not know the details of your question.

Answer (score 2):

The question is very obscure. I hope that I can edit this answer once the question is clarified.

Based on your question and the attached image, it appears that whatever you are using to measure the overlap is faulty. I downloaded your image and divided the element into four equal sections. Exactly one section was outside the colored element, which means that `150px` of the element is overlapping. (200/4*3 = 150) I used Sketchbook and copied/pasted the same 'I-beam' shape.

[image]

Here is my method for finding issues with CSS positions:

1. What are the `padding` and `margin` set to for the element in question?
2. What are the `padding` and `margin` set to for the element containing the element in question?
3. Am I using the correct `position` property? Remember:

> An element with `position: relative;` is positioned relative to its normal position. Setting the top, right, bottom, and left properties of a relatively-positioned element will cause it to be adjusted away from its normal position. Other content will not be adjusted to fit into any gap left by the element.
>
> An element with `position: static;` is not positioned in any special way; it is always positioned according to the normal flow of the page. HTML elements are positioned static by default. Static positioned elements are not affected by the top, bottom, left, and right properties.
>
> An element with `position: fixed;` is positioned relative to the viewport, which means it always stays in the same place even if the page is scrolled. The top, right, bottom, and left properties are used to position the element.
>
> An element with `position: absolute;` is positioned relative to the nearest positioned ancestor (instead of positioned relative to the viewport, like fixed). However; if an absolute positioned element has no positioned ancestors, it uses the document body, and moves along with page scrolling. Note: A "positioned" element is one whose position is anything except `static`.
>
> An element with `position: sticky;` is positioned based on the user's scroll position.

4. What is the `position` property of the element containing the element in question?
5. Am I using tools that might be confusing what I am doing? Am I using, perhaps, a browser extension that is not accurate or reliable? When in doubt, use a pencil and a piece of paper to figure out how things ought to look.
6. (VERY IMPORTANT) If I have to ask a question, I must provide all the information needed for someone to answer! Communities can provide excellent feedback, often more than we need, but they are helpless if they do not have a well-formed question. When in doubt, post more code than less.

Answer (score 1):

You intuition about what `top: -150px` is right. In a minimal example, what you're trying to do works:

```js
/**
 * all of this is for demonstration purposed only,
 * to calculate and display how much space is left between the two divs
 */

const elOne = document.querySelector('.one');
const elTwo = document.querySelector('.two');
const elDiff = document.querySelector('#diff');

const elOneTop = elOne.getBoundingClientRect().top
const elTwoTop = elTwo.getBoundingClientRect().top

const diff = Math.abs(elOneTop - elTwoTop);

elDiff.innerText = `Diff is ${diff}px`;
```

```css
.one {
  background: linear-gradient(90deg, #ad057f, #310492);
  height: 200px;
}

.two {
  box-shadow: 0 0 6px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.25);
  height: 200px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  position: relative;
  top: -150px;
  width: 80%;
}



/**
 * everything after here is for demonstration purposes only,
 * to display how much space is left between the two divs
 */

.one {
  position: relative;
}

.measurement {
  align-items: center;
  display: flex;
  font-size: 12px;
  height: 50px;
  justify-content: center;
  left: 0;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  width: 100%;
}

.measurement span {
  background: #fff;
  border: 2px solid #000;
  display: inline;
  padding: 2px;
  position: relative;
}
  
.measurement::before {
  background: #000;
  content: '';
  display: block;
  height: 100%;
  left: 50%;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  transform: translateX(-50%);
  width: 2px;
}
```

```html
.one's 200px height - .two's shift should leave 50px difference

<div class="one">
  200px tall
  
  <!--
    this div for demonstration purposes only,
    to calculate and display how much space is left between the two divs
   -->
  <div class="measurement"><span id="diff"></span></div>
</div>

<div class="two">
  Top -150px
</div>
```

You can play with this example at https://codepen.io/henry/pen/XWJzKqO

Note that this works in Chrome without any "reset" styles (like changing `box-sizing`). Note also that the "50px" measure box is positioned absolutely, and isn't affecting the "test" box's placement in any way.

Basic answer to "What is the problem?" is you have some in HTML or CSS or both that you're forgetting is impacting things. I recommend looking at the "computer" tab next to the "styles" tab in your screenshot to see all the CSS you're applying to a given DOM element.

To answer more exactly we'll need more information.

Answer (score 0):

Without being able to look at your code to see what you want to accomplish, it's also possible to use `margin-top` to move an element.

```css
.element {
  height: 100px;
  width: 100%;
}

.colorized {
  background: linear-gradient(to left, red, blue)
}

.text {
  border: 1px solid #000;
  box-sizing: border-box; /* adjust for border */
}

.text:not(.another) {
  margin-top: -20px;
}
```

```html
<div class="colorized element">

</div>
<div class="text element">text</div>
<div class="another text element">text</div>
```

Another option can be to `translate` the element, but then you need to use `margin` anyway to drag the following element towards the translated one.

```css
.element {
  height: 100px;
  width: 100%;
}

.colorized {
  background: linear-gradient(to left, red, blue)
}

.text {
  border: 1px solid #000;
  box-sizing: border-box; /* adjust for border */
}

.text:not(.another) {
  --translated-distance: -20px;
  transform: translateY( var(--translated-distance) );
  margin-bottom: var(--translated-distance);
}
```

```html
<div class="colorized element">

</div>
<div class="text element">text</div>
<div class="another text element">text</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Having had a look over this problem, I appreciate it is an awkward question to word.

I think having built this myself, can you press the ellipsis in the top corner of your browser and set the zoom to 100%. This can be done pressing 'ctrl + 0' or 'cmd + 0'.

I think it is correctly moving the element, however if it is zoomed in it has increased the height of the box in question. Looking at your image, you wish for the box to be 3/4 above the end of the previous box (200px height - 150px from the top). The image appears to reflect that.

Here is a stack fiddle for you to play around with:

```css
* {
 margin: 0;
 padding: 0;
 box-sizing: border-box;
}

.container {
 width: 100%;
 height: 300px;
 background-image: linear-gradient(to right, red , yellow);
}

.container-overlap {
 width: calc(100% - 200px);
 height: 200px;
 margin: 0 auto;
 position: relative;
 top: -150px;
 border: 5px solid green;
 box-shadow: 0px 0px 6px 1px rgba(0,0,0,1);
}

.extra-container {
 width: 100%;
 height: 300px;
 background-color: purple;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
</div>
<div class="container-overlap">
 Testing the overlap!
</div>
<div class="extra-container">
</div>
```

Seems like a simple solution to a mind boggling question, failing that - you have a working example to build your code from here too.